# How do I change my XML to have hibernate to define the DataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

can someone please show me how to  change my XML to have hibernate to define the DataSource. I would like to see a good sample of it.  Below is my xml file. can someone post what it would look like with hibernate defining the DataSource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <!-- these are C3P0 properties --> 
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${database.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${database.maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />

        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.uftwf.schoolvisit.model.VisitModel</value>
                <value>org.uftwf.schoolvisit.model.NameID_lookupModel</value>
                <value>org.uftwf.schoolvisit.model.School_lookupModel</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">${format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">25</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is a comment that someone made to me about my XML so I am trying to see what he is talking about:

***You should simplify your own life by using those hibernate.*** properties to define the DataSource in order to avoid a maintenance nightmare down the road by mixing them. It will help to avoid confusion like this. And don't hardcode the values that you have data properties for.*

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Data sources are defined externally to Hibernate, and then Hibernate makes use of the datasource(s) in its Session(s).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: this is a comment that someone made to me about my xml "You should simplify your own life by using those hibernate.* properties to define the DataSource in order to avoid a maintenance nightmare down the road by mixing them. It will help to avoid confusion like this. And don't hardcode the values that you have data properties for."

Comment: This is really a matter of style.  Other than pointing at the datasource itself, you don't need to define any props about your datasource in your Hibernate config (appears that you are mixing C3PO props into your Hibernate session config).  Also, if you define the datasource inside your session config, you lose the ability to dynamically switch between datasources in your Session via the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`, if you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
        <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
        <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="20"/>
</bean>
```